# How to access dynamically inserted elements by name in a form on IE7?

Tags: javascript, forms, internet-explorer, dom

Take the following code, which dynamically inserts an INPUT element to a FORM, if it is not yet  there.

```
<form id="form1">

  <input type="button" value="Add field if not yet there" onclick="addField()" />

</form>

<script>

    function addField()
    {
        var form1 = document.getElementById("form1");
        var field = form1.elements["test"];
        if (!field)
        {
            field = document.createElement("input");
            field.type = "text"
            field.name = "test";
            form1.appendChild(field);
        }
    }

</script>
```

This code is working on all modern browsers, but fails to work on IE7 (field is undefined).

On IE7, the "elements" collection does not seem to contain the elements that have been added dynamically to the DOM.

Are there any known workarounds (apart from keeping a reference to the created element or setting an identifier)?

Comment: Why not just give the dynamic field an ID, since ID's are unique for the entire HTML document?  Then you won't have to check form1's children for the element, just check the document.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534184.aspx

Comment: I'm not too keen on this technique since I actually dynamically create hidden fields in a generic control. Yes, I could set the ID to the same value as the name (provided it's unique), and get the element by ID. But I'm wondering if there are any other workarounds allowing you to keep working with the name. Any links related / discussing the problem are welcome.

Comment: OK CBroe, I suppose that you refer to _Microsoft JScript allows you to change the name at run time. This does not cause the name in the programming model to change in the collection of elements, but it does change the name that you use for submitting elements._, which would explain why (although it seems this behaviour has changed starting from IE8.

Comment: you could use jQuery to get the element by name http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/